# CRA 2.0 How to setup proxy in React?

Tags: reactjs, http-proxy-middleware

In CRA 2.0 proxy property on the package.json does not work. After some research, I came across an article suggesting to use `http-proxy-middleware`. I created an `setupProxy.js` in the src of my client folder(React side). That contains the following code

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");
module.exports = function(app) {
  console.log("Setup proxy is ever called");
  app.use(proxy("/api/auth/google", { target: "http://localhost:5000/" }));
};
```

What am I supposed to do after this. Where should I import the `setupProxy.js` file. From where it is gonna receive `app`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `proxy` value in `package.json` does still work in CRA 2, but it now only accepts a string, more complicated proxy options have to be put in `src/setupProxy.js` as you are doing. But be careful, if you leave the `proxy` property in `package.json` CRA will use that and ignore your `setupProxy.js` file.

You don't need to import `setupProxy.js` anywhere, CRA will find it as long as it's in `src`.

Don't worry about where `app` comes from, that variable will be provided at runtime.

Your example will work, I've tried it (as long as you remove the old proxy string from `package.json`). But the `console.log` will not be logged to the terminal (I'm not sure why).

Further reading, the PR where this change was introduced: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/5073